# Text selecting on tapping <li> item

Tags: javascript, css, touch, html-lists

I'm using a ul with several child lis for navigation with html/javascript and css.  Problem is, on tapping, it selects the Menu1 text (like it would when you want to copy text), while opening the menu.  Using Windows 8, ie11, on surface tablet.  I don't want the text selected, how can I stop this?

```
<ul id="nav" class="dropdown dropdown-horizontal">
 <li><a href="../page1.html">Page1</a></li>
 <li><a href="../page2.html">Page2</a></li>
 <li><a href="../page3.html">Page3</a></li>
 <li aria-haspopup="true" style="cursor:pointer"><span class="dir">Menu1</span>
    <ul>
     <li><a href="../item1.html">Menu Item 1</a></li>
     <li><a href="../item2.html">Menu Item 2</a></li>
    </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `-ms-user-select: none;`?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try something like this:

```
<li>Page1<a href="../page1.html"></a></li>
<li>Page2<a href="../page2.html"></a></li>
<li>Page3<a href="../page3.html"></a></li>
```

And then CSS

```
li {
    position:relative;
}

li > a {
    position:absolute;
    display:block;
    height:100%;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:2;
}
```

This would put the anchor on top of the text, thereby making it clickable but not allowing the text to be copyable.